# Getting Failed lookup view on a EJS that is there"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am getting this error message only when the app is live on Heroku. This is the current url https://nel-ims-dafe2ed28b48.herokuapp.com/ . When I try to access another route called https://nel-ims-dafe2ed28b48.herokuapp.com/current I get an "Internal Server Error" and the console gives me this error message Error: Failed to lookup view "currentDevices" in views directory "/app/views"

The app.js file looks like this:

```html
require('dotenv').config({path:'./.env'});
const express = require('express');
const colors = require('colors');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session'); 
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')   
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');
const {localDb,prodDb} = require('./db/users');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
console.log(__dirname +'/views');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use(urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//Routes
const forgetPasswordRouter = require('./routes/forgetPassword')
const homeRouter = require('./routes/login');
const changePasswordRouter = require('./routes/changePassword');
const signupRouter = require('./routes/signup');
const userRoute = require('./routes/users');
const oldRoute = require('./routes/oldDevices');
const deviceAge= require('./routes/deviceAge');
const currentdevice = require('./routes/currentDevices');

prodDb();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys:['abcd']
}));
app.use(flash())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.use((req, res,next)=>{
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash(('success_msg'));
    res.locals.error_msg  = req.flash(('error_msg'));
    res.locals.error = req.flash(('error'));
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    
    next();
});

app.use(homeRouter);
app.use(changePasswordRouter)
app.use(forgetPasswordRouter);
app.use(signupRouter);
app.use(userRoute);
app.use(deviceAge);
app.use(oldRoute);
app.use(currentdevice);



module.exports = app;
```

the CurrentDevices controller method looks like this:

```html
exports.getCurrentDevicePage = async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const {token} = req.cookies;
       
        const data = await getCurrentDevices(token);
        // console.log(data);

        if(!data){
            throw new Error('No data to display')
        }
    
        res.render('currentDevices',{devices:data});

    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);

        req.flash('error_msg', `${error.message}`);

        res.render('currentDevices',{devices:[]});
    }
    
}
```

I did a console log of the variable 'token' and 'data', they hold the expected information. The issue seems to be with `res.render('currentDevices',{devices:data});`
I've searched on stack overflow and other sites and the issues seem to stem from the views not being properly configured with `app.set()` I keep seeing the same response and I'm pretty sure that my code is written the same.  What's weird about it is that it's the only route that is giving me this issue. This only occurs when you are logged in. You should be able to replicate it when you create an account. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: `const currentdevice` your naming is inconsistent with other names. Maybe you are misspelling the file name? check that file exists in `app/views`